# reading command line argument

Tags: c

can anyone point me to the problem over here? This compiles but it won't print anything. I need to compare the string from command line argument with the string "hello".
Thanks!

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <string.h>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  { 
      if (argc == 0) 
      {
        printf("No arguments passed!\n");
      }

      char *str = argv[1];
      if(strcmp("hello", str)==0)
      {
        printf("Yes, I find it");     
      }

      else
      {
        printf("nothing"); 
      }

    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: what is the output when you run this?

Comment: there is no output, that's the problem

Comment: Seems to work fine for me, can you post the exact command line you are using? It should be printing something. If there is no argument however, you will get a segmentation fault.

Comment: aren't your running like `./program hello` ?

Comment: Your code fails to check the value of `argc`, which is just a plain error. There's no point musing about ifs and buts.

Comment: i run program > test hello or > test hi and the output is nothing

Comment: Is this snippet the *exact* copy of your test program? I guess not.

Comment: Also, you should put a `\ņ` at the end of your printf statements, otherwise your output may become cluttered together with the prompt.

Comment: @LeoStorm delete `program` and recompile, your `program` is maybe another program.

Comment: give it a different name like lstest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My ESP suggests that you're running this in an interactive editor/debugger, such as Microsoft Studio.   You probably haven't configured the environment to pass any command-line parameters, so you expect to see `nothing` as your output.

However, you access `argv[1]`, which does not exist, creating a seg-fault, and the program aborts before there is any output.

To fix this, check the value of `argc` first, and make sure you don't access invalid memory.

Also, I recommend putting a `\n` at the end of each `printf` to help flush any buffered output to the console.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      if (argc == 0) 
      {
        printf("No arguments passed!\n");
      }
      else if(strcmp("hello", argv[1])==0)
      {
        printf("Yes, I find it\n");     
      }

      else
      {
        printf("nothing\n"); 
      }

    return 0;
  }
```

When you run this, you should see:

```
$prompt:  myprogram
No arguments passed!

$prompt:  myprogram hello
Yes, I find it

$prompt:  myprogram world
nothing
```

Comment: Technically correct answer - Loved the ESP part. Being from networks background, i initially thought Encapsulation security payload and i said like what???? took a second and realized the sensory perception. Specially +1 for humour

Comment: ... except: `i run program > test hello or > test hi and the output is nothing`

Comment: well, i made couple of changes as you can see, still nothing

Comment: It is very unlikely that after these changes, ALL THREE scenarios produce no output at all.   Please describe exactly which scenarios you run:  How do you run them? What arguments do you pass and how?  Do all three fail exactly the same way?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the command you're using to run it. As you commented:

> i run program > test hello or > test hi and the output is nothing

The `>` is redirecting output, and ends up giving you no command line arguments. What you want is simply `program hello` without the output redirection.

Comment: i think '>' is the cmd prompt

Comment: yeah probably. in any case, abelensky's answer is a great one

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    if (argc < 2 || 0 != strcmp("hello", argv[1]))
        printf("nothing\n");     
      else
        printf("yes, found it\n"); 

    return 0;
  }
```

and output

```
bash-3.2$ gcc 1.c -o 1
    bash-3.2$ ./1 hello1
    nothing
    bash-3.2$ ./1 hello
    yes, found it
    bash-3.2$ ./1
    nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling your program something different to 'test'